# An extension of the disjunction property in modal logic

Tags: modal-logic

A normal modal propositional logic $\Delta$ has the disjunction property if and only if

> For any formulas $A_1,\dotsc,A_n$, if $\Box A_1 \vee \dotsb\vee \Box A_n \in \Delta$ then $A_k\in \Delta$ for some $k$ with $1\leq k\leq n$.

Let us say that $\Delta$ has the *extended* disjunction property if and only if

> For any formulas $A_1,\dotsc,A_n$ and non-modal formula $A_0$, if $A_0 \vee \Box A_1 \vee \dotsb \vee \Box A_n \in \Delta$ then $A_k\in \Delta$ for some $k$ with $0\leq k\leq n$.

Does there exist a normal modal propositional logic with the disjunction property but not the extended disjunction property?

I came across the second property in some unpublished notes of Kit Fine's from the '70s, but I do not know of much discussion of it elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your question, but doesn't it work to consider the modal propositional theory with four propositions, $P$, $\neg P$, $\top$, and $\perp$, with $\Box P = P$ and $\Box \neg P = \perp$? Looks to me like this satisfies the disjunction property, but not the extended disjunction property, since $\neg P \vee \Box P = \top$ and yet $P \neq \top$. Sorry if I've misunderstood your question and this isn't useful.

Comment: @user509184 That's not a [normal modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_modal_logic).

Comment: Sometimes one finds oddities of typesetting software by looking at things here.  Looking at $ A_0 \vee \Box A_1 \vee ... \vee \Box A_n,$ coded as `A_0 \vee \Box A_1 \vee ... \vee \Box A_n`, one instantly sees that the last $\vee$ does not have the conventional amount of horizontal space to its right. I had a guess about the reason for that, and I'm not yet sure my guess was wrong, but when I changed the code to `A_0 \vee \Box A_1 \vee \cdots \vee \Box A_n`, that fixed the issue, so that what appeared was $A_0 \vee \Box A_1 \vee \cdots \vee \Box A_n.$ MathJax usually$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: MathJax usually treats `...` as if it were `\dots`, unlike LaTeX which renders `...` differently from `\dots`. I suspect there's some obvious reason for this difference in horizontal spacing after `\vee`, but I don't know what it is. $\qquad$

Comment: (In the comment from user509184 above, one sees $\Box \neg P = \perp,$ coded as `\Box \neg P = \perp`, whereas the code `\Box \neg P = \bot` yields instead $\Box \neg P = \bot,$ which is the correct amount of horizontal space after the "equals" sign. In a case like that, the reason is clear and it's what I expect. I'm guessing I'll figure the other one out.

Comment: ok, I think I see it: When `\vee` has nothing to its left, it is treated as a unary rather than binary operation symbol, hence less space to its right, just as is done with "plus" and "minus" signs, etc. But that doesn't fully explain why `...` and `\ldots` are treated as nothing to its left, whereas `\cdots` is "something".

Comment: @MichaelHardy, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1173036), a test: $A_0 \vee \Box A_1 \vee \ldots \vee \Box A_n$ vs. $A_0 \vee \Box A_1 \vee ... \vee \Box A_n$.  It does not seem that `\ldots` is treated the same as `...`.  I am surprised by your [claim](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1173030) that MathJax usually treats `...` as `\dots`; I have not observed that. (Also, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1173032), I had always thought `\perp` and `\bot` were `\let` one to the other, but apparently not: $\Box\neg P = \perp$ vs. $\Box\neg P = \bot$.)

Comment: @LSpice : ok, Let try something: $a+\ldots+z$ versus $a+...+z$ versus $a+\text{...}+z. \qquad$ These three look different from each other, so apparently MathJax does not treat `...` as `\dots`. But LaTeX, as opposed to MathJax, would render `...` like the third example here, and MathJax doesn't do that.

Comment: @LSpice : I should have said in _some_ contexts MathJax treats `...` like `\dots`. $\qquad$ $a,...,z$ versus $a,\ldots,z \qquad$ Those two look identical to me, whereas in LaTeX rather than MathJax the first one would have appeared as $a,\text{...},z \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453397/an-extension-of-the-disjunction-property-in-modal-logic#comment1173069_453397), at this point we are at dire risk of going past off topic and out into the wilderness, but I think that they are not the same: $\begin{array}{|l|} a,...,z \\ a,\ldots,z \end{array}$

Comment: @LSpice : They're very close. Huge numbers of mathematicians are so callous about these things that in LaTeX, not MathJax, they write `a,...,z` and then see $a,\text{...},z$ and don't notice that it looks conspicuously different from $a,\ldots,z.$ Somehow they still walk around without bumping into things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extended disjunction property is equivalent to plain disjunction property for all normal modal logics $\Delta$.

Assume that $\Delta$ contains
$$A_0\lor\bigvee_{i=1}^n\Box A_i,$$
where $A_0$ is box-free.

Let $P$ denote the set of propositional variables occurring in the formula. For each $a\colon P\to\{0,1\}$, let $\sigma_a$ denote the substitution such that $\sigma_a(p)=p^{a(p)}$ for all $p\in P$, where $p^1=p$, $p^0=\neg p$.

Since $\Delta$ is closed under substitution and classical reasoning, $\Delta$ contains
$$\bigwedge_a\Bigl(\sigma_a(A_0)\lor\bigvee_{i=1}^n\Box\sigma_a(A_i)\Bigr).\tag{$*$}\label{star}$$

If $A_0$ is a classical tautology, then $A_0\in\Delta$ and we are done. Otherwise, \eqref{star} implies
$$\bigvee_a\bigvee_{i=1}^n\Box\sigma_a(A_i)\tag{$**$}\label{starstar}$$
by classical propositional reasoning: for any assignment $e$, there is $a$ such that $e(\sigma_a(A_0))=0$, thus the rest of the disjuction holds under $\sigma_a$.

Applying the disjuction property to \eqref{starstar}, $\sigma_a(A_i)\in\Delta$ for some $i=1,\dotsc,n$ and $a\colon P\to\{0,1\}$. Applying closure under substitution once more, $\Delta$ contains $\sigma_a(\sigma_a(A_i))$, which is equivalent to $A_i$ over **K**.

The argument above applies not just to normal modal logics, but also to quasinormal logics, and even more generally, to all logics $\Delta$ that are closed under modus ponens and box-free substitutions, and that contain the tautologies of **E**. Here, **E** is the smallest logic that includes classical logic, and is closed under modus ponens and under the rule $A\leftrightarrow B\mathrel/\Box(A\leftrightarrow B)$.

Comment: I had a déjà vu feeling when writing down the argument. I think I used it before somewhere on this site.

Comment: Oh, of course: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/290882).

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453397/an-extension-of-the-disjunction-property-in-modal-logic#comment1172917_453410), "déjà écrit"? 

Comment: Thanks! I asked that previous question, but I didn't notice the connection to your answer. My bad!

Comment: There isn’t really much of a connection that I can see. It’s just that a similar trick works for both.